# How do make entire Angular ng-grid editable?

Tags: javascript, grid, angularjs

Using the code below, you can make a column editable.

```
cellTemplate: '<input style="width:100%;height:100%;" class="ui-widget input" type="text" ng-readonly="!row.selected" ng-model="COL_FIELD"/>' },
```

How do you make the entire grid editable? The docs say look at wiki. Where is the wiki??

Comment: [There](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki).

Comment: A downvote for asking for the wiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can enable an excel-style mode by setting "enableCellEdit: true" and "enableCellSelection: true" in > v2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The wiki on GitHub is in the subnav in the tabs; look over next to "issues" etc.